# "Authentication token manipulation error" on first time login as root on Debian 10

Tags: debian

I just installed Debian 10 on a lxc container. Passwords given by the web hosting company must be changed on the first time you login.

If my personal password was successfully changed, this did not work for root's password. I always have this message when I type and enter the new password:

`su: Authentication token manipulation error`

Please not that I typed the good password first, and that I am not at all able to login as root.

Do I have a solution ?

Comment: What was the command you entered to change the root password (don't show the passord)? The error message "Authentication token manipulation error" is code for what ever it was that you tried it didn't work.

Comment: I just entered "su" to log in as root. Debian asked me to change the password because it was the first login.

Comment: Try "sudo passwd root"  to change the password.